# CVDisplayLink and Triple-Buffering

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, opengl

I've been using CVDisplayLink for an OpenGL based project, using an NSOpenGL context and a regular double-buffered pixel format.

This is fine, but I'm interested in playing with triple-buffering pixel formats - using the *NSOpenGLPFATripleBuffer* flag

Apple's documentation has scant reference to *NSOpenGLPFATripleBuffer*, so I'm trying to understand under what circumstances it might be useful. [This](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2794/4) article gives a reasonable description of what I'm trying to achieve.

What I'm not clear about it how it interacts with a *DisplayLink* driven approach.

It seems the idea behind *DisplayLink* is that the drawing routine will be sync'd to the display refresh, which doesn't seem compatible with how a triple-buffered context would work.

Is the correct approach here to do away with *DisplayLink* and to just render full-throttle into the triple-buffered context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triple buffering provided by the `NSOpenGLPFATripleBuffer` flag is a render ahead queue, not page-flipped triple buffering as described in the article. As such you still need to set the swap interval to 1 (vsync'ed) to avoid tears or drops (on newer macOS the system will opt to drop the frame instead of tearing). It also results in an extra frame of latency unlike the page-flipping approach.

Metal on the other hand supports true page-flipped triple buffering. It might be possible to emulate the page-flipped approach in OpenGL by rendering to an FBO, then inside the displaylink callback you can just present the last fully rendered frame.

Also note that on any version of OSX I tried (10.8 - macOS 11+?), NSOpenGLPFATripleBuffer actually only gives you a double buffered context.

You can use the following snippet to verify the behavior:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <OpenGL/gl.h>
#import <OpenGL/glu.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>

@interface MyOpenGLView : NSOpenGLView
@end

@implementation MyOpenGLView

+ (BOOL)canDrawOpenGL {
    return YES;
}

- (void)prepareOpenGL {
    // Set up OpenGL context and other properties
    [super prepareOpenGL];
    [[self openGLContext] makeCurrentContext];
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glFinish();
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    
    static float i = 0;
    i += 0.01;
    glClearColor(0.0f, i, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Swap the buffers to display the rendered image
    [[self openGLContext] flushBuffer];
//  glFlush();
}

@end

int x = 0;
MyOpenGLView *glView;

CVReturn MyDisplayCallback(CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink,
    const CVTimeStamp *inTime,
    const CVTimeStamp *outTime,
    CVOptionFlags flagsIn,
    CVOptionFlags *flagsOut,
    void *displayLinkContext) {
        [glView prepareOpenGL];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ){
            printf("-------\n");
            CVTimeStamp out;
            CVDisplayLinkGetCurrentTime(displayLink, &out);
            printf("Bef: %llu\n", out.videoTime);
            [glView drawRect:NSZeroRect];
            CVDisplayLinkGetCurrentTime(displayLink, &out);
            printf("Aft: %llu\n", out.videoTime);
        }
        exit(0);
        
        return kCVReturnSuccess;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // Set up the application and window
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSApplication *app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
        NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 400)
            styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask
            backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
            defer:NO];
        [window setBackingType:NSBackingStoreBuffered];
        
        // Create an NSOpenGLPixelFormat object with double buffering enabled
        NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attribs[] = {
            NSOpenGLPFATripleBuffer,
            NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated,
            0
        };
        NSOpenGLPixelFormat *pixelFormat = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attribs];
        
        // Create an NSOpenGLContext object with the pixel format
        NSOpenGLContext *glContext = [[NSOpenGLContext alloc] initWithFormat:pixelFormat shareContext:nil];
        
        // Set the pixel format and context for the view
        glView = [[MyOpenGLView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 400) pixelFormat:pixelFormat];
        [glView setOpenGLContext:glContext];
        
        // Optionally see what happens when using a CAOpenGLLayer instance
    
//      [glView setWantsLayer: YES];
//      [glView.layer setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor].CGColor];
        
        // Set up the window and run the application
        [window setContentView:glView];
        [window makeFirstResponder:glView];
        [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    
        
        GLint a = 1;
        [glContext setValues:&a forParameter:NSOpenGLCPSwapInterval];
        
        CVDisplayLinkRef _link;
        CVDisplayLinkCreateWithCGDisplay(CGMainDisplayID(),&_link);
        
        
        CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(_link, MyDisplayCallback, NULL);

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            printf("Starting\n");
            CVDisplayLinkStart(_link);

        });
        
        [app run];
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On older OSX (pre-10.11) with a single-buffered context the first swap immediately returns, and the second swap blocks (because you only have one buffer to draw into, so the queued commands for second render pass cannot be sent). With a double-buffered context the first swap immediately returns, the second swap returns, and it's the third swap that is stuck waiting for a free buffer. Triple and double buffered behave the same.

On newer OSX (post OS11, which uses GL to Metal translation layer) on a single-buffered context each swap immediately blocks until completion. On a double buffered context the first swap immediately returns, and the second swap blocks until completion.

Comment: Wow.. thank you @1110101001 for the super detailed response, that's incredibly helpful. Epic necromancy on display here, coming up to 8 years now!

Comment: @TimKane It should also be noted that CAOpenGLLayer might actually be page-flipped. From my experiments it never blocks on swap, and if you have multiple swaps queued upon a vsync it always renders the latest. In fact with CAOpenGLLayer you render to an FBO so it's probably implementing the manual strategy I mentioned, managing the buffers itself. (And this also means that with CAOpenGLLayer setting the single vs double buffered property probably doesn't have any actual effect. Although I have not decompiled the code to verify).